# MySQL Select all users with no transactions within a month

Tags: mysql

Need to get all inactive members of a platform.

A member is active if at least a transaction is made within the current month and otherwise inactive.

Here is the procedure I used for solving this.
Joined both members and transactions table together grouped by the members' Id in order to select members with empty (NULL) total sales for the month.

```
$date = date('Y-m');
$query = "select members.*, 
  sum(mybuys.amount) as total_sales
  from members 
  LEFT JOIN mybuys ON  members.id = mybuys.userid
  where mybuys.timed LIKE '$date%'
  group by members.id
  having total_sales IS NULL
";
```

The problem with this approach is that the query returns empty.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Don't use `like` on dates.

Comment: `date(Y-m)` should be `date('Y-m')`. Also, _"A member is active if at least a transaction is made within the current month"_ - You should probably check for something like 30 days back instead, or everyone would be counted as inactive on the first day of every month if they haven't logged in that specific day, unless that is the behaviour you want?

Comment: Oh! the date() part was an oversight.
This is exactly how it should behave -"A member is active if at least a transaction is made within the current month" Magnus Eriksson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want members who had no transactions in a given month, I would expect something like this:

```
select m.*
from members m
where not exists (select 1
                  from mybuys mb
                  where mb.member_id = m.id and
                        mb.timed >= $month_start and
                        mb.timed < $month_start + interval 1 month
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `mybuys(member_id, timed)`.

I'm not sure what `amount` has to do with this.  The question is about whether or not any rows exist, not about whether any rows exist with a non-zero amount.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but the the query is just too slow for large number of records in members table

Comment: @Fresher . . . Try adding the index I just added to the answer.